# DJI WaypointActionType for CAMERA_FOCUS and CAMERA_ZOOM

Tags: android, dji-sdk

The documentation online did not have these two actions (CAMERA_FOCUS and CAMERA_ZOOM). Could anyone tell me what parameters are acceptable for these actions? I'm assuming it would only work with the Inspire drones which is what I'm working with. Thank you.

Current documentation:
[image]

CAMERA_FOCUS and CAMERA_ZOOM available in SDK:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the zoom function waypoint action basically works the same way as the setOpticalZoomFocalLength function in DJICamera.

You will need to calculate the focal length value to pass in base on the current lens you are using. The max and min focal length values you can find under getOpticalZoomSpec function.

More information on setOpticalZoomFocalLength in DJI android sdk api:

https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/cn/faq/cn/api-reference/android-api/Components/Camera/DJICamera.html#djicamera_camerasettings_setopticalzoomfocallength_inline

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what is your meaning.

I guess you want to know how to control camera focus/zoom using DJI MSDK? refer to their class reference and call the corresponding function. EZ as ABC

[image]

https://developer.dji.com/cn/mobile-sdk/documentation/faq/cn/api-reference/android-api/Components/Camera/DJICamera.html

[image]

Comment: Ah sorry, I was unclear, updated my original post with better description.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few more missing.  I see the following (including the ones you mention):

```
CAMERA_ZOOM(7),
CAMERA_FOCUS(8),
FINE_TUNE_GIMBAL_PITCH(16),
RESET_GIMBAL_YAW(17);
```

I'll see what I can find out and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Ken, appreciate if you have any info on "FINE_TUNE_GIMBAL_PITCH". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DJI got back to me the other day,  apparently these values are inactive currently,  they do nothing in the current release but it's possible that a future release will include the functionality.

No date,  version or timeline was indicated on when they might work.

For now,  ignore them,  they will likely be removed in the next update.